# Importar txt para postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Criei o seguinte arquivo txt:

```
'Granada', current_timestamp
'Grecia', current_timestamp
'Guatemala', current_timestamp
'Guiana', current_timestamp
'Guine', current_timestamp
'Guine Esquatorial', current_timestamp
'Guine Bissau', current_timestamp
'Haiti', current_timestamp
'Honduras', current_timestamp
'Hungria', current_timestamp
'Lemen', current_timestamp
'Ilhas Marechal', current_timestamp
'India', current_timestamp
'Indonesia', current_timestamp
'Irao', current_timestamp
'Iraque', current_timestamp
'Irlanda', current_timestamp
'Islandia', current_timestamp
'Israel', current_timestamp
'Italia', current_timestamp
'Jamaica', current_timestamp
'Japao', current_timestamp
'Jibuti', current_timestamp
'Jordania', current_timestamp
'Laus', current_timestamp
'Lesoto', current_timestamp
'Letonia', current_timestamp
'Libano', current_timestamp
'Liberia', current_timestamp
'Libia', current_timestamp
'Listenstaine', current_timestamp
'Lituania', current_timestamp
```

Para atualizar a tabela pais, uso o seguinte comando, no pgAdmin4:

```
COPY pais (pais, ultima_atualizacao)
FROM 'C:\Users\magno\Documents\arquivo_paises.txt'
DELIMITER ',';
```

Mas esse comando tem como resultado, o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR:  date/time value "current" is no longer supported
CONTEXT:  COPY pais, line 1, column ultima_atualizacao: " current_timestamp"
********** Error **********

ERROR: date/time value "current" is no longer supported
SQL state: 0A000
Context: COPY pais, line 1, column ultima_atualizacao: " current_timestamp"
```

Comment: Aqui não adicionamos RESOLVIDO no título, apenas o aceite da resposta é suficiente ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua no seu arquivo texto a palavra current_timestamp por now():

```
'Granada', now()
'Grecia', now()
'Guatemala', now()
'Guiana', now()
'Guine', now()
'Guine Esquatorial', now()
'Guine Bissau', now()
'Haiti', now()
'Honduras', now()
'Hungria', now()
'Lemen', now()
'Ilhas Marechal', now()
'India', now()
'Indonesia', now()
'Irao', now()
'Iraque', now()
'Irlanda', now()
'Islandia', now()
'Israel', now()
'Italia', now()
'Jamaica', now()
'Japao', now()
'Jibuti', now()
'Jordania', now()
'Laus', now()
'Lesoto', now()
'Letonia', now()
'Libano', now()
'Liberia', now()
'Libia', now()
'Listenstaine', now()
'Lituania', now()
```